# How can I program an Atmega32u4 over USB with this schematic?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, programmer, avrdude, atmega32u4

This is my first time trying to program an Atmega32u4. I made a PCB with the following schematic:

[image: schem]

Now I've soldered all the parts onto the PCB, and I've plugged a micro usb cable from my computer into J1.

I assumed that when I pressed down SW1, the bootloader would activate and and the device would register as a serial device on my computer, so that I can program it using avrdude.

However, when I pressed the reset button, I couldn't find which port it's communicating over. I tried the command `avrdude -p m32u4 -P USB -c avr109` to intialise it, just in case that port happened to work, but the output was:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "USB": No such file or directory

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

So what's the issue here? Is there something wrong with my schematic, or with my software approach? Again, I'm a complete beginner to this, so any information at all is useful.

**EDIT:** I plugged it into a different USB port on my computer and now `lsusb` lists: "Bus 001 Device 020: ID 03eb:2ff4 Atmel Corp. atmega32u4 DFU bootloader", however when I try to use dfu-programmer (as has been suggesteed), this happens:

```
j4cob-antergos :: /sys/class/tty » sudo dfu-programmer atmega32u4 dump --debug 4        5 ↵
     target: atmega32u4
    chip_id: 0x2ff4
  vendor_id: 0x03eb
    command: dump
      quiet: false
      debug: 4
device_type: AVR
------ command specific below ------

0%                            100%  Reading 0x7000 bytes...
[ X  ERROR
```

**EDIT 2:** I tried to use avrdude instead again, and this happened:

```
j4cob-antergos :: ~ » sudo avrdude -p m32u4 -P usb -c flip1                                              1 ↵

avrdude: Warning: Failed to read USB device string 1: Input/output error
avrdude: Warning: Failed to read USB device string 2: Input/output error
avrdude: Warning: Failed to read USB device string 3: Input/output error
avrdude: Warning: USB bDeviceClass = 255 (expected 254)
avrdude: Error: Failed to reset DFU state: Input/output error
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading |                                                    | 0% 0.00savrdude: Error: DFU_DNLOAD failed: Input/output error
avrdude: Error: Failed to get DFU status: Input/output error
avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega32U4", rc=-1
avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-1

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

This is looking more hopeful, but at this point it seems like my schematic just doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: This link http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc7618.pdf says that the chip has a factory boot loader and how to use it.  People also seem to like https://dfu-programmer.github.io/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf):

[image]

Your schematic doesn't have a bypass capacitor on VCC.  Adding one might help.  To maximize its effectiveness, solder it on as close to a pair of VCC/GND pins on the chip as possible.  Looking at your schematic, the best bet would be pins 14 and 15.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks for looking into that! :)

Comment: This _kind of_ worked, I'm getting a [different issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/425079/issue-with-programming-atmega32u4-lfuse-memory-not-accessible-using-flip?noredirect=1#comment1056688_425079) now.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to program a USB bootloader onto the microcontroller using the ISP interface and a programmer. Only then will it understand how to load programs over USB. AVRs don't ship with a bootloader, they only have hardware *support* for bootloaders. If you have an ISP programmer (e.g. AVIRSPmkII, AVR Dragon, AVR ICE, etc) and wire a header up to the appropriate pins of the AVR, you could, in principle, burn the bootloader Arduino uses for the Leonardo onto your board.

I stand corrected. Excerpt from [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc7618.pdf).

> The 8bits mega AVR with USB interface devices are factory configured
>   with a USB bootloader located in the on-chip flash boot section of the
>   controller.

Comment: Is that true even with the Atmega32u4? I read somewhere that it shipped with some kind of bootloader.

Comment: as far as I know it is true of all 8-bit AVRs, but hey I could be wrong.

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf In the features list on the title page of this datasheet it says "Parts using external XTAL clock are pre-programed with a default USB bootloader". I could be misunderstanding this, though.

Comment: @JacobGarby Updated answer, you're quite right... maybe avrdude doesn't support it out of the box, dunno

Comment: I've updated my question. Does the new information provide any sort of new answer? :)