# ATmega32U4 without USB: how to handle usuned pins

Tags: usb, avr, atmega, microchip, atmel

On the [ATmega32U4](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) MCU there are several pins related to USB:

- VBUS
- D+
- D-
- UCAP
- UGND
- UVCC

In the datasheet and in almost all reference schematics I find on the Internet, it's explained how to connect those pins when you need the USB.

On my board, instead, I don't need the USB at all.
Hence, I want to understand how to connect those pins.

I'm not sure if I can just leave them floating or else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet does have that information.

You can make a self-powered USB device as per the datasheet diagrams and imagine the USB cable is unplugged, which gives enough information how the pins should be connected without USB connection.

Answer (score 1):

> *On my board, instead, I don't need the USB at all. Hence, I want to
> understand how to connect those pins.*

Grab a schematic that uses the USB interface like this: -

[image]

And ask yourself what connectivity is important if there isn't anything plugged into the USB connector. You'd end up with this: -

[image]

Schematic image taken from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/424912/how-can-i-program-an-atmega32u4-over-usb-with-this-schematic).

So, should VBUS be connected to Vcc - you can always double check that in the data sheet and, is it any great hardship to make that connection anyway? What about UVCC and UGND - well, is it really any problem to connect them to Vcc and GND

Comment: It's not a problem. But I'm trying to understand, not to guess... For example, the capacitor on UCAP may be mandatory because it's the output of the internal regulator. I cannot know if omitting it may lead to some issues.

Comment: @Mark then you should thoroughly read the data sheet from front to back and double check everything.